# Creating a type Allowing Keys of Types A and B, Excluding Type C for Most Keys, and Restricting Type C to Only Key2

Tags: typescript

I need to create an interface/tuple/object that receives any key as long as they are of types A and B, but it cannot receive a value of type C, but I want the key key2 to receive only values ​​of type C, it is important that only the key2 can receive values ​​of this type, the others cannot.

this is my try:

```js
type A = "val a"
type B = "val b"
type C = "val c"

type T = {
  [key: string]: A | B
  key2: C
}

const obj1: T = {
  key1: "val a",
  key2: "val c",
  key3: "val b",
}
```

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way. See the linked q/a for various approaches and workarounds